# If $f:R\to S$ is an $R$-algebra and $P$ is a projective $S$-module, then $pd_R(P)\le pd_R(S)$.

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module

The title basically says it all. If $f:R\to S$ is an $R$-algebra and $P$ is a projective $S$-module, then I need to show that $pd_R(P)\le pd_R(S)$. Here $pd_R(A)$ refers to the projective dimension of the $R$-module $A$, i.e. the minimum possible length of a projective resolution $P\to A.$

Unfortunately I don't even know how to start this. I think I'm just hitting a mental roadblock. Of course I can assume that $pd_R(S)$ is finite, say $pd_R(S)=n$, but then what? I can take a projective resolution of $S,$ but I don't really see what that does. I think I want to use what Weibel calls the "pd lemma," which basically says

> The following are equivalent for an $R$-module $A$:
>
> 1. $pd(A)\le d$
> 2. $\mathrm{Ext}^n_R(A,B)=0$ for all $n>d$ and all $R$-modules $B$
> 3. $\mathrm{Ext}^{d+1}_R(A,B)=0$ for all $R$-modules $B$
> 4. If $\;0\to M_d\to P_{d-1}\to\cdots\to P_0\to A\;$ is any resolution of $A$ with the $P_i$'s projective, then $M_d$ is projective.

There's something easy that I'm missing and I know it because I did the surrounding problems without too much trouble. Any hint would be great.

---

This is (part of) Exercise 4.1.3 of Weibel's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*.

Comment: How does projective dimension behave for direct sums of modules? For direct summands?

Comment: @John Palmieri The dimension of the sum is the supremum of the dimensions of the summands.

Comment: Oh wait that does it doesn't it? If you type that as an answer then I'll accept it but I'll write it out explicitly for anyone seeing this in the future.

Comment: Your answer is fine, and anything I add would be redundant. I don't care about the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ is a projective $S$-module, so it is a direct summand of a free module, say $P\oplus M=S^{(A)}$. The dimension of a sum is the sup of the dimensions of the summands, so $$pd_R(P)\le pd_R(S^{(A)})=pd_R(S).$$